# Can SSH be fault-tolerant, or, is there a way to overcome RST messing up my TCP connections (some kind of retry pipe at both ends?)

Tags: ssh, tcp

I'm trying to use "scp" to copy TB-sized files, which is fine, until whatever router or other issue throws a tantrum and drops my connections (lost packets or unwanted RSTs or whatever).

```
 # scp user@rmt1:/home/user/*z .
 user@rmt1's password:
 log_backups_2019_02_09_07h44m14.gz                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 16% 6552MB   6.3MB/s 1:27:46 ETAclient_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
 lost connection
```

It occurs to me that (if ssh doesn't already support this) it should be possible for something at each end point and in between the connection to simply connect with its peer, and when "stuff goes wrong", to transparently just bloody handle-it (to re-try indefinitely and reconnect basically).

Anyone know the solution?

My "normal" way of tunnelling remote machines into a local connection is using ssh of course, catch-22 - that's the thing that's breaking so I can't do that here...

Comment: A UDP-based VPN might solve that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

SSH uses TCP, and TCP is generally designed to be relatively fault-tolerant, with retries for dropped packets, acknowledgements, and other techniques to overcome occasional network problems.

If you're seeing dropped connections nevertheless, then you are seeing *excessive* network problems, more than any standard protocol can be expected to handle, or you are seeing a malicious attacker *intentionally* try to disrupt the connection, which cannot be avoided.  Those are both issues that no reasonable network protocol can overcome, and so you're going to have to deal with them.  That's true whether you're using SSH or some other protocol.

You could try using SFTP instead of SCP, because SFTP supports resuming (e.g., `put -a`), but that's the best that's going to be possible.  You can also try a command like `lftp`, which may have more scripting possibilities to copy and retry (e.g., `mirror --continue --loop`), and can also use SFTP under the hood.

Your best bet is to find out what the network problem is and get that fixed.  `mtr` may be helpful for finding where your packet loss is.

Comment: Yes, the irony of using TCP and having to find a way to make it reliable is not lost on me.  Assorted reasons for dropouts include my router restarting its NAT tables (sends RST packets, telling TCP to drop the connections, grr), actual connection losses (mobile networks), and occasional "netsplit" weirdness (the machines in question are the other side the the planet to me, and the copy's I'm running take days).  My preference is not to MANUALLY resume - but to get it to just sort itself out automatically.